# Model fitting VS model selection: what works best?

Tags: cross-validation, modeling, model-selection, validation, fitting

Suppose we have two candidate models to predict a variable $y$ given a variable $x$, where $\alpha$ is a model parameter.

$$\hat y=M_1(x,\alpha)$$
$$\hat y=M_2(x,\alpha)$$

Conceptually, we could combine them two into a single model, by introducing an additional parameter $\beta$.

$$M(x,\alpha,\beta)=\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        M_1(x,\alpha), & \text{for } \beta=1 \\
        M_2(x,\alpha), & \text{for } \beta=2 \\
    \end{array}\right.$$

**Now, what approach would produce the best out-of-sample predictor? Why?**

**Approach 1**

- split the samples into in training and validation sets
- select the model that generalises best, out of $M_1(x,\alpha)$ and
  $M_2(x,\alpha)$
- fit the selected to the whole set of historical samples
- use the fitted model to predict

**Approach 2**

- fit the combined model $M(x,\alpha,\beta)$ to the historical samples
- use the fitted model to predict

thank you!

Comment: How do you propose to learn the combined model? It seems that $\beta$ would be a hyperparameter and unlearnable in general. Unless you have a way around that, option B won’t work.

Comment: @Arya You can learn $\beta$ by doing grid search for example. The method you use to optimise a parameter (e.g. grid search, calculus, etc.) does not make it necessarily a parameter (which you would optimise with model fitting) versus an hyperparameter (which you would optimise with model selection). Does that make sense?